# Using Sendgrid to send verifiction e-mail not working

Tags: php, email, twilio, sendgrid

I really need some help.

So, I'm making a promptbase for school and I made a signup system where you put your email and password and you get an account. Afterwards, it should send an email to the user to verify it. I made an account on sendgrid to do this and I have an API key, but my code keeps telling me it doesn't work.

This is what my code looks like:

```
<?php 

if(!empty($_POST)){
        
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  
  $options = [
      'cost' => 12,
  ];
  
  $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
  
  try {
    // Connect to database
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=promptswap', "evi", "12345");

    // Check if email is already in use
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email = :email");
    $query->bindValue(":email", $email);
    $query->execute();
    $count = $query->fetchColumn();

    // If email is not in use and is valid, create a new user
    if ($count == 0 && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      // Insert user into database
      $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)");
      $query->bindValue(":email", $email);
      $query->bindValue(":password", $password);
      $query->execute();

      // Send verification email using SendGrid API
      $from = new SendGrid\Email("PromptSwap", "noreply@promptswap.com"); //here I use my email that I registered on sendgrid
      $to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $email);
      $subject = "Verify Your Email Address";
      $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(32)); // Generate random token
      $verificationLink = "http://yourwebsite.com/verify.php?email=".urlencode($email)."&token=".urlencode($token); // Change this to your website's URL and verify.php file
      $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", "Click the following link to verify your email address: <a href='$verificationLink'>$verificationLink</a>");
      $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);
      $apiKey = '*****'; //my api key is here where the ***** is
      $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
      $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);

      header("Location: verify.php"); // Change this to your website's verify.php file
    } else {
      $error = "Invalid email or email already in use.";
    }
  } catch (Throwable $error){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
  }
}   

?>
```

The error that I get is that the `new SendGrid\Email` line (and the others) are not recognised, it is an undefined object.

> "Undefined type 'SendGrid\Mail\HtmlContent'.intelephense(1009)"

I did install everything in my composer with `composer require sendgrid/sendgrid` and I also put this `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` in the code, then it still didn't work. I also tried `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`. Then I also tried to do it like this:

```
use SendGrid\Mail\From;
use SendGrid\Mail\HtmlContent;
use SendGrid\Mail\Mail;
use SendGrid\Mail\PlainTextContent;
use SendGrid\Mail\Subject;
use SendGrid\Mail\To;
```

And change my code like this:

```
use SendGrid\Mail\From;
$from = new From("test@example.com", "Example User");
```

My terminal tells me that everything works:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\promptswap\AIAI-prompt-platform-main>composer require sendgrid/sendgrid
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update sendgrid/sendgrid
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
No security vulnerability advisories found
Using version ^8.0 for sendgrid/sendgrid
```

And I also wrote it like this:

```
$from = new SendGrid\Email("PromptSwap", "evivermeeren@hotmail.com");
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, $email);
$subject = "Verify Your Email Address";
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(32)); // Generate random token
$verificationLink = "http://yourwebsite.com/verify.php?email=".urlencode($email)."&token=".urlencode($token); // Change this to your website's URL and verify.php file
$content = new SendGrid\Mail\HtmlContent("text/html", "Click the following link to verify your email address: <a href='$verificationLink'>$verificationLink</a>");
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);
$apiKey = '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'; // Replace with your API key
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
$sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
```

Really NOTHING worked! Does anyone know how I can fix this? Or another way to work with an email verification? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't abbreviate or paraphrase error messages. Post the exact, full error message and the stack trace. Thanks.

Comment: "Undefined type 'SendGrid\Mail\HtmlContent'.intelephense(1009)"

Comment: Please [edit] your question when you have important updates.

Comment: Also is that actually a runtime error, or just something in your IDE? It's possible that actually the IDE can't detect it properly for some reason, but the code would still run fine if you execute it.

Comment: I edited my question, thank you for your patience, I'm still a beginner. It's the error that I get in my VSCode, so the IDE. I'll try to run it now and let you know what it said.

Comment: It seems like it's an issue with your IDE finding the file. Perhaps restart the IDE or clear its cache and restart it. Do you get a similar error when you run the code from the command-line/terminal?